# Inserting and updating data grid row in the linked db table using sqlite, wpf and C#

Tags: c#, sqlite, datagrid, wpf-controls

My sqlite code for linking db table to datagrid is:

```
 sqlitecon.Open();
 string Query2 = "Select * from Security_details "; 
 SQLiteCommand createCommand2 = new SQLiteCommand(Query2, sqlitecon);  createCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery();
 SQLiteDataAdapter dataAdp2 = new SQLiteDataAdapter(createCommand2);
 DataTable dt2 = new DataTable("Security_details");
 dataAdp.Fill(dt2);
 datagrid_security.ItemsSource = dt2.DefaultView;
 dataAdp2.Update(dt2); 
 sqlitecon.Close();
```

This code links db table to datagrid during form load event.

I want user to be able to:

- add new rows on datagrid get inserted into db
- edit existing rows on datagrid get updated into db.

Here in following query are my database fields

```
SQLiteCommand comm = new SQLiteCommand("update Security_details  " + 
      "set id=@id,Code=@Code,Description=@Description,Rate=@Rate," + 
      "Qty=@Qty,Amount=@Amount,Remarks=@Remarks where id=@id", sqlitecon);
```

Please tell me the set of commands for inserting and editing db table through datagrid ?Thanks

Comment: Note: Here I am not using any FrameWork...I have searched it on google i found many articles that use entity framework for doing this task on datagrid

Answer (score 3):

Move the declaration of the `SQLiteDataAdapter` to the global class level and declare also a `SQLiteCommandBuilder` there. Then, before binding your data to the grid, initialize the SQLiteCommandBuilder that will create the UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE commands appropriate for your table automatically (provided that the SELECT returns the primary key of the table)

At this point, when you are ready to submit your data to the database, call the `Update` method of the global SQLiteDataAdapter instance

```
public class YourClass
{
     SQLiteDataAdapter dataAdp2;
     SQLiteCommandBuilder cmdBuilder;
     .....


     public void BindMyGrid()
     {
          sqlitecon.Open();
          string Query2 = "Select * from Security_details "; 
          SQLiteCommand createCommand2 = new SQLiteCommand(Query2, sqlitecon);                

          dataAdp2 = new SQLiteDataAdapter(createCommand2);
          cmdBuilder = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(dataAdp2);
          DataTable dt2 = new DataTable("Security_details");
          dataAdp2.Fill(dt2);
          datagrid_security.ItemsSource = dt2.DefaultView;
          sqlitecon.Close();
     }
     ....
     public void SubmitData()
     {
          dataAdp2.Update((datagrid_security.ItemsSource As DataView).Table);
     }
     ......
}
```

If you need a more in depth discussion of this process [you could read this MSDN article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308055/en-us), it is rather old, regards SQL Server and it is in VB.NET, but the base concept is the same.

Comment: public void SubmitData()
     {
          dataAdp2.Update((datagrid_security.ItemsSource As DataView).Table);
     } will this function edit as well as insert into db table?

Comment: Can't find now the exact reference page for SQLite, but [this page for the base class DbDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z1z2bkx2.aspx) explains the functionality expected for this method. Yes, it should update, insert and delete your MODIFIED/INSERTED and DELETED rows